# Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

After adding **mvc:resource** my application throwing error like

```
"javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [com.test.web.controller.AppController@190cf5c]: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?"
```

when i use below configuration it's workin fine,

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

 <mvc:resources mapping="/help/**" location="/help/" />
<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="xmlFileViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="location">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="order">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

But when i add my controller's i'm getting error. pls check the below configuration

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd">

 <mvc:resources mapping="/help/**" location="/help/" />
<!-- View Resolver -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean id="xmlFileViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.XmlViewResolver">
    <property name="location">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="order">
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <!-- maximum file size (1 megabyte) -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="6048576" />
</bean>

<bean id="urlMapping"   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">


    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <!-- Login -->
            <prop key="/login.htm">appController</prop> 
            <prop key="/index.htm">appController</prop>

            </props>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean name="appController" class="com.test.web.controller.AppController" >
    </bean>
```

but if i remove

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/help/**" location="/help/" />
```

this tag, it's working fine. I spend lot time to figure this one :( Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd start by updating from your mixed but all ancient versions of Spring to 4.0.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using? In your XML you seem to be using XSDs from both Spring 2.5 and Spring 3

Comment: Could you show the source of your `AppController` ?

Comment: @geoand previously used 3.0.2 now moving to 3.0.5(reason->mvc not supported by 3.0.2)

Comment: @MuthuramuPeriyaiah First of all, update the XSD references in your Spring XML configuration. Second, are you absolutely sure that you don't have any Spring 2.5 jars on the classpath? Third, post the code of `AppController` please

Comment: @geoand I tried updating xsd, no improvements. and I'm sure, there is no 2.5jars. 
actually it's huge app, in appcontroller i got too many controllers like
"public ModelAndView index(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
 {
//code
}"
nothing more than this. You want any more info buddy?

Comment: Please, post the source of your `AppController`.

Comment: After adding two tags it is finally worked :)

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/> 
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
     <property name="order" value="0"/>
   </bean>

Comment: Thank you so much for your valuable time guys :)

Answer (score 1):

After adding these two tags, it is finally worked..

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter"/> 
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="order" value="0"/>
</bean>
```

Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add this adapter too.

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a portlet, like liferay portlet then you need to add

...`<bean class="org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>`
also make sure that your controller has @Controller annotation and your controller method has @RequestMapping("VIEW")